# Javascript: How to display an animated (loading) gif while a chart is being created

Tags: javascript, html

On a webpage I have some charts that I'm creating with pChart and they take a while to generate.

In order to make the page finish loading in a reasonable amount of time, I've put instead of these charts some pictures (also generated with pChart) that just have a text that says 'Click here to load chart XYZ'.

My problem is that when the user clicks on the picture, the div shrinks to zero and that causes other divs to change position. So I'm thinking of displaying a loading (animated) gif in place of the charts while they are generated. This should also provide a visual indication after the click that the chart is being generated, as well as prevent the div from shrinking.

Here's the code that I'm using so far:

```
<head>
<script>
   function myFunction(where){
      var content = '<img style="some style" src="chart.php">';
      document.getElementById(where).innerHTML = content;
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="id1" style="some style">
     <img style="some style" src="click-to-load.php" onclick="myFunction('id1')">
</div>
</body>
```

The above works as I've described: the div shrinks and the user doesn't have any other visual indication that something is happening in the background and there will eventually be displayed something as a result of the click.

So, how do I change the onclick event to display a gif, request the php chart (which is just a jpeg image), and when it's ready dsplay it instead on the loading gif?

Answer (score 0):

On one hand, to avoid the shrinking issue, you could set a width and a height on `<div id="id1"></div` in order to keep this room even if there is nothing inside. The rest of elements in the page will remain where they are.

On the other hand, when you click on the initial image, you want two things to happen: 1) to swap this image for a gif, 2) and to execute a php file that will load some content.

You only need to set `var content` with the gif you want to show up, which will happen inmediately, and execute the php file, that will take a while, and then replace the gif with its content.

<strike>By the way, the `src` attribute should have the path to the image.</strike>

Comment: OK, how do I do the last part: replace the gif with the actual chart (which is a jpeg picture generated by a php file)?

Comment: I don't know the context of your project, but this seems more like a php question. Will you serve again the full page from the server? If so, change the <img> element. Are you using AJAX to refresh only a part of the page? Tell to the server file where is that part.

Comment: Neither. I'm using the onclick property to run the script I listed in the header part of html, which changes the innerHTML of the div with another <img>.

Comment: I have been having a look at the documentation of pChart, and if you check http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.delayed.rendering.html you will see that there is a delayedLoading.js script where it uses this same loading gif in another scenario, but I am sure you will be able to extract this part of the code where it loads this gif until image is generated and sent to the browser.